# How to store user data and when the data is repeated it should show error

Tags: java

Example
if there are 4 slots named A1,B1,C1,D1. If first user enters A1 and when the second user enter the same slot it should error it has already been chosen.

Comment: Hello. please try to provide an example describing the user input.

Comment: EXAMPLE:  User one selects A1 out of the four slots and second user also selects A1 it should shown an error

Answer (score 1):

The built-in class [`java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) can do that. Read the docs, perhaps search for some usage examples :)